Skip struct field when deriving Debug
When deriving Debug, what is the best approach to skip a specific struct field that doesn't implement Debug? For example:
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct MySettings {
    pub max_size: usize,
    pub max_queue_size: usize,
    // this guy doesn't implement Debug
    pub my_type: Box<dyn MyType + Send + Sync>
}

I can't add a crate to the Cargo.toml.
Right now I am providing a blank impl for that field like this:
impl std::fmt::Debug for (dyn MyType + Send + Sync){
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        Ok(())
    }
}


There is this question for generics and this question for Fn. tl;dr you can't derive your Debug with the standard macros.

I suspect the best approach will be to impl Debug manually, rather than using the derive macro.

You will need to implement Debug manually, but if you want to be maximally lazy, you can still essentially get Rust to derive it for you. You can create a struct inside the Debug implementation and give it the same name, MySettings, and choose which fields it contains.
use std::fmt;

pub struct MyType;

pub struct MySettings {
    pub max_size: usize,
    pub max_queue_size: usize,
    // this guy doesn't implement Debug
    pub my_type: Box<MyType>,
}

impl fmt::Debug for MySettings {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> Result<(), fmt::Error> {
        #[derive(Debug)]
        struct MySettings<'a> {
            max_size: &'a usize,
            max_queue_size: &'a usize,
        }

        let Self {
            max_size,
            max_queue_size,
            my_type: _,
        } = self;
        
        // per Chayim Friedman’s suggestion
        fmt::Debug::fmt(&MySettings { max_size, max_queue_size }, f)
    }
}


Instead of the write!(), better to forward it: fmt::Debug::fmt(&MySettings { ... }, f).
